# Mixitup plugin multi able check boxes

Tags: jquery, html, css

i want to make all the checkboxes checked on load, but this doesnt seam to work

usualy you would add this peice of code but nothing is working
load: {
          filter: '.square,.circle,.triangle'
      },

please see codepen http://codepen.io/anon/pen/GZxwzq

```js
// To keep our code clean and modular, all custom functionality will be contained inside a single object literal called "checkboxFilter".

var checkboxFilter = {
  
  // Declare any variables we will need as properties of the object
  
  $filters: null,
  $reset: null,
  groups: [],
  outputArray: [],
  outputString: '',
  
  // The "init" method will run on document ready and cache any jQuery objects we will need.
  
  init: function(){
    var self = this; // As a best practice, in each method we will asign "this" to the variable "self" so that it remains scope-agnostic. We will use it to refer to the parent "checkboxFilter" object so that we can share methods and properties between all parts of the object.
    
    self.$filters = $('#Filters');
    self.$reset = $('#Reset');
    self.$container = $('#Container');
    
    self.$filters.find('fieldset').each(function(){
      self.groups.push({
        $inputs: $(this).find('input'),
        active: [],
      tracker: false
      });
    });
    
    self.bindHandlers();
  },
  
  // The "bindHandlers" method will listen for whenever a form value changes. 
  
  bindHandlers: function(){
    var self = this;
    
    self.$filters.on('change', function(){
      self.parseFilters();
    });
    
    self.$reset.on('click', function(e){
      e.preventDefault();
      self.$filters[0].reset();
      self.parseFilters();
    });
  },
  
  // The parseFilters method checks which filters are active in each group:
  
  parseFilters: function(){
    var self = this;
 
    // loop through each filter group and add active filters to arrays
    
    for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
      group.active = []; // reset arrays
      group.$inputs.each(function(){ 
        $(this).is(':checked') && group.active.push(this.value);
      });
     group.active.length && (group.tracker = 0);
    }
    
    self.concatenate();
  },
  
  // The "concatenate" method will crawl through each group, concatenating filters as desired:
  
  concatenate: function(){
    var self = this,
    cache = '',
    crawled = false,
    checkTrackers = function(){
        var done = 0;
        
        for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
          (group.tracker === false) && done++;
        }

        return (done < self.groups.length);
      },
      crawl = function(){
        for(var i = 0, group; group = self.groups[i]; i++){
          group.active[group.tracker] && (cache += group.active[group.tracker]);

          if(i === self.groups.length - 1){
            self.outputArray.push(cache);
            cache = '';
            updateTrackers();
          }
        }
      },
      updateTrackers = function(){
        for(var i = self.groups.length - 1; i > -1; i--){
          var group = self.groups[i];

          if(group.active[group.tracker + 1]){
            group.tracker++; 
            break;
          } else if(i > 0){
            group.tracker && (group.tracker = 0);
          } else {
            crawled = true;
          }
        }
      };
    
    self.outputArray = []; // reset output array

   do{
    crawl();
   }
   while(!crawled && checkTrackers());

    self.outputString = self.outputArray.join();
    
    // If the output string is empty, show all rather than none:
    
    !self.outputString.length && (self.outputString = 'all'); 
    
    //console.log(self.outputString); 
    
    // ^ we can check the console here to take a look at the filter string that is produced
    
    // Send the output string to MixItUp via the 'filter' method:
    
   if(self.$container.mixItUp('isLoaded')){
     self.$container.mixItUp('filter', self.outputString);
   }
  }
};
  
// On document ready, initialise our code.

$(function(){
      
  // Initialize checkboxFilter code
      
  checkboxFilter.init();
      
  // Instantiate MixItUp
      
  $('#Container').mixItUp({
    load: {
    filter: '.square,.circle,.triangle'
   },
    controls: {
      enable: false, // we won't be needing these
      toggleFilterButtons: true
    },
    animation: {
      easing: 'cubic-bezier(0.86, 0, 0.07, 1)',
      duration: 600
    }
  });    
});
```

```css
body{
  background: #68b8c4;
}

body, button{
  font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', arial, sans-serif;
  color: #333333;
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
 
/**
 * Form & Checkbox Styles
 */

.controls{
  background: #333;
  padding: 2%;
}
 
fieldset{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  margin: 0 1em 0 0;
  padding: .5em;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

/*.checkbox{
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  border: 3px soldi green;
}

.checkbox input[type="checkbox"]{
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  cursor: pointer;
  margin: 0;
  opacity: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}

.checkbox label{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
  padding-left: 1.5em;
}

.checkbox label:before,
.checkbox label:after{
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
}

.checkbox label:before{
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 18px;
  height: 18px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  background: #ddd;
  border-radius: 3px;
}

.checkbox label:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border-radius: 2px;
  background: #68b8c4;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.checkbox input:checked ~ label:after{
  opacity: 1;
}

.checkbox input:focus ~ label:before{
  background: #eee;
}
*/
/**
 * Container/Target Styles
 */

.container{
  padding: 2%;
  min-height: 400px;
  text-align: justify;
  position: relative;
}

.container .mix,
.container .gap{
  width: 100px;
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 5%;
}

.container .mix{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 5%;
  background: white;
  display: none;
}

.container .mix.green{
  background: #a6e6a7;
}

.container .mix.blue{
  background: #6bd2e8;
}

.container .mix.circle{
  border-radius: 999px;
}

.container .mix.triangle{
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border: 50px solid transparent;
  border-top-color: #68b8c4;
  border-left-color: #68b8c4;
}

.container .mix.sm{
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

/**
 * Fail message styles
 */

.container .fail-message{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  opacity: 0;
  pointer-events: none;
  
  -webkit-transition: 150ms;
  -moz-transition: 150ms;
  transition: 150ms;
}

.container .fail-message:before{
  content: '';
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  height: 100%;
}

.container .fail-message span{
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-weight: 700;
}

.container.fail .fail-message{
  opacity: 1;
  pointer-events: auto;
}



#ck-button {
    margin:4px;
    background-color:#ffffff;
    border-radius:25px;
    border:1px solid #D0D0D0;
    overflow:auto;
    float:left;
}

#ck-button:hover {
    background:red;
}

#ck-button label {
    float:left;
   /* width:4.0em;*/
  padding:10px 15px;
}

#ck-button label span {
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px 0px;
    display:block;
}

#ck-button label input {
    position:absolute;
    top:-20px;
}

#ck-button input:checked + span {
    background-color:#911;
    color:#333;
}
```

```html
<div class="controls" id="Filters">
  <!-- We can add an unlimited number of "filter groups" using the following format: -->
  
  <fieldset>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value=".square"/>
        <span>Local Events</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value=".circle"/>
        <span>Beaches</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
       <label>
         <input type="checkbox" value=".triangle"/>
         <span>Attractions</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
        <input type="checkbox" value=".triangle"/>
        <span>Places of Interests</span>
      </label>
    </div>
  </fieldset>
  
  <fieldset>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".white"/>
        <span>January</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>February</span>
      </label>
    </div>
     <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>March</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>April</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>May</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>June</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>July</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>August</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>September</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>October</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>November</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox" id="ck-button">
      <label>
      <input type="checkbox" value=".green"/>
        <span>December</span>
      </label>
    </div>
    
  </fieldset>
  
</div>

<div id="Container" class="container">
  <div class="fail-message"><span>No places were found</span></div>
  
  <div class="mix triangle white lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix square white sm"></div>
  <div class="mix circle green lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix triangle blue lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix square white lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix circle blue sm"></div>
  <div class="mix triangle green lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix square blue lrg"></div>
  <div class="mix circle white lrg"></div>
  
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
  <div class="gap"></div>
</div>
```

any help would be greatly appreciated

many thanks
Dan

Answer (score 0):

In general couldn't you assign the property on load?  For example if I want to check all of the boxes I can do:

```
$('.checkbox').prop('checked',true)
```

and anything that is of the class checkbox will be updated to a checked state.  In your function you could possibly do a callback that executes this on load.

It may also be that those elements are not populated on the page when your javascript executes, therefore it assumes these elements do not exist and therefore does nothing to them.

-K

Comment: humm i did try this but no such luck :-(